# How to remove View Licenses button from showAboutDialog | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

I want to remove view licenses menu from showAboutDialog. How to remove this button. This is the code.

```
                    showAboutDialog(
                        context: context,
                        applicationName: 'Jobs',
                        applicationIcon: Container(
                            height: 65,
                            width: 65,
                            child: Image.asset('assets/employment.png')),
                        applicationVersion: '1.0.0',
                        children: [
                          Text('This is the body'),
                        ]);
```

Comment: Why couldn't you use AlertDialog, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html